# Astronomy picture of the day Vue application

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-component

I am new to vue and I am trying to call the APOD (Astronomy picture of the day) from NASA so that I can display a new picture every day.  I am making a new Vue component called Picture.vue where I do all of the accessing of the APOD api.  I have been able to get the proper url for the picture I want to display from the response payload (and store in a variable called 'apod') but simply put I don't know how to put the "apod" variable as a 'src' value into either a regular HTML 'img' tag or a vuetify 'v-img' tag.  I have a feeling this could be solved with v-bind but like I said I am new to Vue so any tips or guidance would be most appreciated.

Picture.vue

```
  <section class="picture">
    <h1>picture Component</h1>
    <v-img src="{{apod}}"></v-img>
  </section>

</template>

<script lang="js">
const url =  "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=" + process.env.VUE_APP_KEY;
const axios = require('axios');
 


  export default  {
    name: 'picture',
    props: [],
    async created () {
      console.log("https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=" + process.env.VUE_APP_KEY);
    //   axios.get(url)
    // .then(response => this.apod = response.data.url);
      const response = await axios.get(url);
      this.apod = response.data.url;
      console.log(response);
    },
    data () {
      
      return {
        apod: null
      }
    },
    methods: {

    },
    computed: {

    },

  state () {
     
  },

   
}


</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
  .picture {

  }
</style>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <v-app>
      <Picture></Picture>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
 import Picture from './components/Picture'
   
export default {
  
  name: 'App',
  
  components: {
    Picture,
  },
  
  
  
  


  data() {
    
    return {
         
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

In summary my question is how can I put the 'apod' variable as the value of 'src' in an image tag (Vuetify or HTML)?

Thanks very much everyone happy easter!

Answer (score 1):

Use :src and remove the {{ }}

like this

```html
<v-img :src="this.apod" />
```